# Cohomology ring of $G$ based on its Sylow.

Tags: finite-groups, homology-cohomology

I have a bunch of notes made from a professor about cohomology that states that

> If $S$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ ($\vert G \vert <\infty$), then 
>   $$H^{\ast}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\leq H^{\ast}(S,\mathbb{F}_p)$$
>   It is, the cohomology ring of $G$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a subring of the cohomology ring of $S$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$

But he wrote it as a theorem without a proof. Anyone knows a reference or a way to prove this theorem?

Comment: Have you learned about the transfer map?

Comment: A bit. I'm still studying it from the Kenneth Brown to understand this theorem (I see that is the theorem 10.3 from the section III of the K.B. Cohomology of groups, but the notation makes it difficult to understand), but if you tell me a more clear reference, I will read it.

Comment: I wrote up a more complete reference. I learned Group Cohomology from Serre's book on Galois Cohomology and from the standard theorems of Algebraic Toplogy (You might not know, but there are objects $BG$, such that $\pi_0Map(S^1, BG)=G$, and $H^*(G; M)=H_{sing}^*(BG; M) $, where the right side denoted the Singular cohomology). I might try Serre's book, but the notation is equally hard to understand :/

Comment: The transfer homomorphism is the same as the defined in the p. 817-818 of the Foot & Dummit Abstract Algebra?

Answer (score 3):

Let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup. There are two standard maps on the group cohomology associated to this: $res_H^G:H^*(G, M)\to H^*(H, M|_H)$ and $tr^G_H:H^*(H, M|_H)\to H^*(G, M)$. We have the relation $tr\circ res(x)=[G:H]x$. Now we wish to show that in the case $H=S$, a Sylow-group of $G$, we have that $res_S^G$ is an injection. Letting $x\in Ker(res_S^G)$, we have $tr\circ res(x)=1=[G:S]x$, but $([G:S], ord(x))=1$ by basic group theory, so that $x=1$. Thus we can conclude using equality $H^*(S, \mathbb{F}_p|_S)=H^*(S, \mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: How are defined $ res^G_H $ and $ tr^G_H $?

Comment: The $res$ is simple, it is simply given by restiction on the cochain level. For a definition of the transfer map, there is an exposition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_(group_theory)

Comment: Oh, thanks! The notation $ord(x) $ is the order of $x$, don't?